Why does importing GLTF in react project gives different result than gltf-viewer?
I made two bars and made a sort of a transparent shader in cycles. I baked the normal maps and exported as .glb.
In the gLTF viewer https://gltf-viewer.donmccurdy.com/ it shows perfectly:-
in gLTF viewer
However when in my react app, it shows a completely different and I'd say worse shader
react
The code is:-
import React, { useRef } from 'react'
import { useGLTF, PerspectiveCamera } from '@react-three/drei'

export function Bars(props) {
  const { nodes, materials } = useGLTF('./src/assets/models/bars.glb')
  return (
    <group {...props} dispose={null}>
      <PerspectiveCamera makeDefault={false} far={1000} near={0.1} fov={22.895} position={[0, 1.36, 3.661]} />
      <pointLight intensity={50.0} decay={2} color="#fdf6ff" position={[0.38, 0, 0.18]} rotation={[Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} />
      <pointLight intensity={50.0} decay={2} color="#fdf6ff" position={[0.699, 2.773, 0.118]} rotation={[-Math.PI / 2, 0, 0]} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.bar1.geometry} material={materials['glow.001']} position={[0.36, 1.706, 0]} scale={[1, 1, 2.532]} />
      <mesh geometry={nodes.bar2.geometry} material={materials['glow.002']} position={[0.571, 0.86, 0]} scale={[1, 1, 2.532]} />
    </group>
  )
}

useGLTF.preload('./src/assets/models/bars.glb')

I tried changing the light intensity but I think its an issue with the material roughness or something. Im pretty new to this and need some help here. Thanks!
Ill also provide the shader:-
I baked the normal map here

I don't think this will solve your issue but you're supposed to use non-color for your normal map's Color space in Blender for it to work properly with GLTF https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/2.80/addons/io_scene_gltf2.html#normal-map

The main difference here is the lighting. In general for anything reflective, you need something to reflect, which point lights don't really provide much of.
Any environment map (or "IBL") would work, often a .exr or .hdr file. The viewer linked above uses THREE.RoomEnvironment, which is a cheap environment generated at runtime without downloading any additional textures.
Typical usage of RoomEnvironment in three.js is something like:
import { RoomEnvironment } from 'three/addons/environments/RoomEnvironment.js';

const environment = new RoomEnvironment( renderer );
const pmremGenerator = new THREE.PMREMGenerator( renderer );

const scene = new THREE.Scene();
scene.environment = pmremGenerator.fromScene( environment ).texture;
environment.dispose();

To load an environment / IBL / HDRI texture you could use HDRLoader or EXRLoader, or in React Three Fiber the <Environment/> component is probably the easiest way.
